# How to call a subroutine exported from a .pm file

Tags: perl

I have a script `Attachments.pm` which contains below

```
package app::Attachments;

use MIME::Lite;

BEGIN {
    use Exporter();
    @ISA    = qw(Exporter);
    @EXPORT = qw(&SendEMmsgAttachments);
}

sub SendEMmsgAttachments {

    $EM_SERVER  = "1234.com";
    $EM_FROM    = "yyy@1234.com"; #hardcoded
    $EM_TIMEOUT = 120;

    my $mailMessage;
    my $mailToEmailAddress;
    my $mailSubject;
    my $mailBody;
    my $mailAttachmentFileName;
    my $mailAttachmentFullPath;

    $mailMessage = MIME::Lite->new(
        From    => $EM_FROM,
        To      => $mailToEmailAddress,
        Subject => $mailSubject,
        Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
    )  or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

    ### Add the text message part
    $mailMessage->attach(
        Type => 'text/csv',
        Data => $mailBody
    )  or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

    ### Add the text file
    $mailMessage->attach(
        Encoding => 'base64',
        Type     => "text",
```

I want to use `SendEMmsgAttachments` in my `testscript.pl` file so that I can send my Excel attachment in email.

Can anyone help me out in resolving the issue?

Comment: In which way does it not work? What did you try? What indicators of failure did you get?

Comment: In your `script.pl` you can `use app::Attachments qw( SendEmmsgAttachments );`

Comment: You can change your `@EXPORTS` line to `@EXPORTS_OK qw( SendEmmsgAttachments );` Notice there is no `&` there.

Comment: Hi @xxfelixx when i am using use app::Attachments qw( SendEmmsgAttachments ); in my code script.pl it is giving ""SendEmmsgAttachments" is not exported by the app::Attachments module" exception

Comment: Remve the '&' in front of the subroutine name.  And while you're at it, move lines 4-6 out of the BEGIN block.  It's not needed.  And add "use strict" somewhere.

Comment: And `@ISA` and `@EXPORT` both need an `our` before them too.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr [perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) says that the `&` for exporting subs is optional, so this should not be the problem.

Comment: @xxfelixxx it's `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`, without the trailing 's'. And the `&` is ok, although it is optional.

Comment: Thanks @tinita, you are correct. Hopefully that was reflected in my answer!

Comment: @tinita yep, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic hello world, using a perl module and script, demonstrating how to use the Exporter library.  See [perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for more details.

**Foo.pm**

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Exporter 'import';

our $VERSION = '0.01';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( bar );

sub bar {
    return "Hello World";
}

1; # Last statement of a .pm file must evaluate to 'true'
```

**try_foo.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Foo qw( bar );

my $msg = bar();

print $msg . "\n";
```

**In action:**

```
perl try_foo.pl 
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

In your program you have this line:

```
use Exporter();
```

This instructs Perl to load the `Exporter` module but to not import anything from it. The parentheses denote that you want to supply your own import list rather than accepting the default list. Since you have nothing in your import list, nothing is imported.

You get around this by inheriting from `Exporter` by adding it to `@ISA`. There's plenty of sample code out there that does this. However, you only really want the `import` routine rather than being a more specific version of an exporting tool. You can do that by asking for only the `import` routine:

```
use Exporter qw(import);
```

After that you need to specify what you want to export by default in `@EXPORT`. For subroutines, leave off the `&`. It's not a big deal but it's common to see it like this:

```
our @EXPORT = qw( SendEmmsgAttachments );
```

If you want your program to specifically ask to import a subroutine you can put that in `@EXPORT_OK`. These entries are not exported by default—they are allowed to be exported if you ask for them:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( SendEmmsgAttachments );
```

The `our` is there to declare the variable as a package variable. Your program isn't bothered by that because you don't `use strict` (which isn't the end of the world but is a good habit).

I'd take your `BEGIN` block and replace it with:

```
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( SendEmmsgAttachments );
```

When you run into problems like this, create the smallest example that shows the problem so you eliminate anything else that might be a problem.